# "Doppelgänger" movie identification

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched this film a few years ago, I'd say it was released after 2010. I thought the main actor was either Elijah Wood, Jake Gyllenhaal, or Tobey Maguire, but a search on IMDB hasn't returned any results.

The film was about a boring guy who had no life. He used to go to work ad punch cards, file papers, etc... He was always on target but never did anything out of the ordinary. There was a girl he liked (if I recall correctly). No one really liked him.

Then one day a new guy turned up at work. Everyone like the new guy. He was funny. Etc...

But this new guy looked exactly like the boring guy (was played by the same actor).

And this new guy (if I recall correctly) would encourage the boring guy to break the rules, etc...

The film had a very dark theme to it. A very muted colour palette. Lots of browns and greys.

**EDIT**

At the same time as being dark it also had an almost comedic sense. (Sort of). I remember he used to sit at a desk in a cubicle office but not like a usual one. It was reminiscent of an old fashioned train carriage (Sort of). He had a desk with a typewriter IIRC.

He would sneak looks between the cubicles at the new guy. He would try to ask people if they though the new guy was familiar or reminded them of anyone. Etc...

**The name**

I'm sure the name of the movie was something along the lines of "Doppelgänger" or "Twins" or something that gave the impression of a copy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is [***The Double***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1825157/) (2013) with Jesse Eisenberg

> A clerk in a government agency finds his unenviable life takes a turn for the horrific with the arrival of a new co-worker who is both his exact physical double and his opposite - confident, charismatic and seductive with women.
>
> IMDB

Comment: YES! Thank you :D Added to my list of movies. Thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

You may are looking for [Enemy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2316411/) (2013) a Denis Villeneuve movie starring Jake Gyllenhaal.

Plot from wikipedia :

> Adam Bell, a solitary college history professor, rents a movie, Where There's a Will There's a Way, on the recommendation of a colleague. Adam sees an actor briefly; the man at the show. Verifying online, Adam identifies the actor as Daniel St. Claire, the stage name for Anthony Claire. Adam rents the other two films in which Anthony has appeared and develops an interest in the man, **who appears to be his physical doppelgänger**. Immediately after this, he searches some boxes in his own house and finds a torn out photo. The intact portion of the photo contains **someone who looks like himself** with some woman's hand over his shoulder. The torn portion of the photo contained the woman, hence her face cannot be identified.
>
> Adam's girlfriend Mary becomes troubled by the change in his behavior. Adam stalks Anthony, visiting his office and calling him at home. **Everyone, including Anthony's pregnant wife Helen, confuses both.**
> [...]

Trailer:

Comment: OK, trailer looks awesome but it's not the film I was looking for. I will definitely be watching it though. Will update the description a bit. Thanks

Comment: After seeing the edit and the other answer (accepted one) I fell like my answer is not even close to your question. By the way, if you watch Enemy, be sure to be aware that it is a complex movie: not everything is explained (or even nothing?).

Comment: No worries :D Thanks for answering though. Got a good movie recommendation out of it :D